# Replace one arrays keys with another arrays keys in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a csv file. I need to read and format in array to be import. My header are look like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
    [2] => shortDescription
    [3] => description
    [4] => productType
    [5] => sku
    [6] => styleCode
)
```

And my values are look like this,

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 185
                [1] => T-shirts
                [2] => this is tshirt short desc
                [3] => This is tshirt desc
                [4] => simple
                [5] => 4585
                [6] => 5292++
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 186
                [1] => test name
                [2] => test short desc
                [3] => test desc
                [4] => configurable
                [5] => 525
                [6] => 555
            )
    )
```

Here I need to replace every key of my values corresponding header values. So my final array should be like this,

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 185
                [name => T-shirts
                [shortdescription] => this is tshirt short desc
                [description] => This is tshirt desc
                [producttype] => simple
                [sku] => 4585
                [stylecode] => 5292++
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 186
                [name] => test name
                [shortdescription] => test short desc
                [description] => test desc
                [producttype] => configurable
                [sku] => 525
                [stylecode] => 555
            )
    )
```

I cannot find out good solution for this. Ca anybody help me to sort this out ?

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried something but it is not working, so didn't posted it here..

Comment: Learn about `array_combine`

Comment: @Elavarasan doesn't matter! Just post it here and show your effort you have done! I mean you are here to learn something and if it would work you wouldn't have to ask, so just show your code and we can show you how to fix your errors

Comment: Initially I have tried with foreach loop inside and inside and it was very crazy. I know I should use array functions but I'm not very familiar with arrays. So only I didnt post my code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through each innerArray with [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and return it combined with the `$headers` as keys and the innerArray as values, which I do with [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php))

```
<?php

    array_walk($values, function(&$v, $k, $headers){
        $v = array_combine($headers, $v);
    }, $headers);

    print_r($values);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Rizier123 ..! It is worked.. Today I have learned  lot ..Thanks again..!

Comment: @Elavarasan You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: If you want you can still add your attempt to you question)